# Doesn't a decentralized P2P protocol need a central authority to tell you where the other nodes are?

Tags: networking, p2p, bitcoin

I am wondering how the *decentralized* P2P networks like Bitcoin discover other nodes. When a brand new node is launched, how does it find out about other nodes to connect? Isn't that a potential exploit to bring the network down and/or do malicious thing with a new node that does not know where to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a list of seed nodes from somewhere.

[Bitcoin has a list](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/how-do-bitcoin-clients-find-each-other) of well-known nodes compiled in, and it also uses a central dynamic discovery mechanism (via DNS I think).

And yes, if your node can be tricked into connecting to an "alternate reality" network, then you are in trouble. But that's hard to pull off.

Comment: I am just wondering whether it wouldn't be easy for government to shut it down then, by targeting the machines on that list. They are probably scattered around the globe, correct? Hackers can target these machines. Wouldn't that effectively halt the network? No seeds, no service. Just wondering how decentralized a P2P protocol really is.

Comment: Well, if you shut down all of the nodes, you shut down the network...   The seed list is only needed at startup. After that, the nodes advertise all other nodes they know about, so there will be many to choose from.

Comment: For more detailed discussion head over to bitcoin.stackexchange.com